# Arc fault breakers are energizing the neutral bus

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 125 amp subpanel which has 6 arc fault breakers. I realized that the pigtail from each arc fault breaker is energizing my neutral bus, I'm reading 120 volts from neutral bus to ground only when I turn on any of the arc fault breakers. I verified that the 120 volts on the neutral bar is in fact emanating from those pigtails from the arc faults. I pulled the pigtails off the neut and energized one of the arc faults and the pigtail was in fact hot 120 volts. I could believe that one of those breakers are bad but all six? I tried each one and they all do this.

Comment: try with any actual load (an incandescent bulb) does it work or not work?

Comment: The AFCIs are not the problem. This is a faulty installation of the subpanel.  Ask for a review of your installation and post some photos. What prompted you to install AFCI breakers?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   gotta agree w/you, most likely a bad neutral connection.  Jeeze, how many times have we run into "bad neutrals" and I've only been here about 2 1/2 years.

Comment: regarding answer number 1- why arc fault breakers were installed is not at all relevant to the question and knowing the "why" will not lead us to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is probably nothing wrong with the breakers. You probably have a bad neutral connection your sub panel and whatever feeds it. Without a good neutral connection, any 120V load (including the arc-detection electronics in the breakers) will pull the neutral bus up to 120V.

If you try to turn on any actual 120V load (an incandescent bulb, a motor, etc.) does it work or not work? If a 120V load doesn’t energize, your neutral is bad.

Comment: Both the phase and neutral pass through the breaker, the white wire is the neutral and carries the detural current for the circuit. The breaker senses current that is flowing through the wire but not through the neutral and trips when its threshold is reached.

Comment: so why does every circuit work fine when i put them on standard breakers? What exactly about the neutral could be bad? Its not open, i read from hot to neutral 120 volts and hot to ground 120 volts (approximately). im saying that there are normal readings of voltage hot to neutral and hot to ground. So the neut is connected, what readings can i take? What tests can i do?

Answer (score 0):

the neutral comes from the main panel, and it is working fine with regular non arc fault breakers, so how can the neutral be bad? neutral is not bonded to the ground in the sub panel but it is in the main panel. the main panel is right from the utility meter, i dont see how or what about the neutral could be bad?

UPDATE!!!  ok people the homeowner built this addition in his backyard and he did much of the electrical. The first day i was there he asked me to makeup the subpanel, add all the breakers which i did. Before i left all the circuits were fine, even the arc fault breaker circuits. So a month later he calls me to help him with a problem of arc faults tripping immediately. I found that the homeowner had unspliced all the feeders that ran to the subpanel from the main panel end because he wanted to change something about the pipe run and connected them back and did it wrong. So i dont know what he did because i didnt fix it, i just today followed up on this and he told me the whole truth this time, thank you all for the effort you put into this,

Comment: Thanks for following up. However, the first paragraph seems like it's a comment addressed to another answer. If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that this isn't how we do things here. Please [edit] your answer to remove that portion. When you have enough rep, you'll be able to make comments on anybody's question or answer, which is were that part should go.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what it is, if i did something swrong then correct it yourself if its such a big deal. Im done with this stack exchange and you guys actually didnt answer my question, it was me who ansswered my own question and i posted the answer just out of courtesy for those who may be curious, but ive done more thazn enough here to feel like ive done the right thing, Small errors like you describe im not bothering with, you can do it.

Comment: OK, your call. When you go to a new skate park and someone politely asks you to follow the rules there (even if they're different than than the rules at your old skate park), you're probably going to pick up your board in a huff and go home from there, too. No worries!